# Auto-translate using Python

Tags: python, translation, google-translate, googletrans

I'm doing an auto-translation script to convert all the data (mixed language) in my Excel file. My file is composed of 3000-4000 raw data with mixed language and I want to translate all the data to "English" but the problem is there are data that are skipped or didn't translate. And also I found one word "Gracias!" not translated to English.

Below is my script hope anyone can help me to fix my current code.

Thanks.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from googletrans import Translator

# Load the Excel workbook
wb = load_workbook('Source.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active

translator = Translator()

# Specify the range of cells containing the data you want to translate
start_row = 2  # Assuming row 1 is header
end_row = sheet.max_row
column_to_translate = 14  # Assuming you want to translate the 14th column

# Add the header "Sentiment"
sheet.cell(row=1, column=column_to_translate + 6).value = "En_Translate"

# Translate each cell in the specified range
for row in range(start_row, end_row + 1):
    cell_value = sheet.cell(row=row, column=column_to_translate).value

    try:
        if cell_value is not None:
            # Translate the cell value to English
            translated_text = translator.translate(cell_value, src='auto', dest='en').text

            # Write the translated text back to the cell
            sheet.cell(row=row, column=column_to_translate + 6).value = translated_text
            
        else:
            # If the cell is empty, set the translated cell to empty as well
            sheet.cell(row=row, column=column_to_translate + 6).value = ""
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error translating cell {row}, {column_to_translate}: {e}")

# Save the updated workbook
wb.save('./Output/Output.xlsx')

print("Translation completed and saved!")
```

I'm expecting to run the code properly so I can work on the next step.

Comment: Have you tried stripping punctuation from the text?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). For us to help you, provide the expected [mre]. We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.